# Mockito issue with List

Tags: java, arraylist, mockito, dao

I have a DAO method which returns a List.

Now I am trying to mock this DAO class in my service layer but when I invoke the DAO method, it is giving me a empty even though I have mocked the DAO method
Below is the sample code snippet,

public class ABCTest {

```
@InjectMocks
ABC abc = new ABC();   

@Mock
private ABCDao dao;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    dao = Mockito.mock(ABCDao.class);
    Mockito.when(dao.getListFromDB()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList("1","2","3"));
}

@Test
public void testServiceMethod() {
    abc.serviceMethod();  // Inside this method when the DAO method is called, it is giving me an empty list even though I have mocked it above.
}
```

Any pointers would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` use `@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)` instead
2. You are calling `dao = Mockito.mock(ABCDao.class)` which overrides the `dao` created by `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`
3. the `ABCDao` instance inside ABC is now different to the `dao` member of your test case.

I can only assume that the following would fail:

```
assertTrue(dao == abc.getDao())
```

Solution: Remove the following line

```
dao = Mockito.mock(ABCDao.class);
```